# Adding complementary proportions below each line of a file

Tags: bash, sed

My file looks like this:

```
0.35 0.45 0.25 0.44 0.35
0.06 0.10 0.14 0.15 0.00
```

and I would like to add below each line the complementary proportions of each value, i.e.:

```
0.35 0.45 0.25 0.44 0.35
0.65 0.55 0.75 0.56 0.65
0.06 0.10 0.14 0.15 0.00
0.94 0.90 0.86 0.85 1.00
```

So far I only managed to insert a string below each line:

```
typeset TMP_FILE=$( mktemp )

touch "${TMP_FILE}"
cp -p proportions_file "${TMP_FILE}"
sed -e 's/$/\nstring after each line/' "${TMP_FILE}" > proportions_file_final
```

where proportions_file is the original file and proportions_file_final the output:

```
0.35 0.45 0.25 0.44 0.35
string after each line
0.06 0.10 0.14 0.15 0.00
string after each line
```

Is there a function I could use instead of "string after each line" that calculates the complementary proportion of the value above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'function printdiff() {
   for (i=1; i<n; i++)
      printf "%.2f%s", (1-a[i]), (i<n-1?OFS:ORS)
}
NR > 1 { 
   printdiff()
}
{
   for (n=1; n<=NF; n++)
      a[n] = $n
}
1;
END {
   printdiff()
}' file

0.35 0.45 0.25 0.44 0.35
0.65 0.55 0.75 0.56 0.65
0.06 0.10 0.14 0.15 0.00
0.94 0.90 0.86 0.85 1.00
```

In one line:

```
awk 'function printdiff(){for (i=1; i<n; i++) printf "%.2f%s", (1-a[i]), (i<n-1?OFS:ORS)} NR>1{printdiff()} {for (n=1; n<=NF; n++) a[n]=$n} 1; END{printdiff()}' file
```